# Opera crashes when I open "Settings"

Tags: windows-7, crash, opera, display-settings

I'm using the latest version of Opera ( 26.0.1656.24 in german) on a Win7 32-bit system. It runs fine, except when I open the Settings Tabs, then it crashes after 1-2 seconds without any error message.

Comment: Does EventViewer show the error message?

Comment: Event Viewer shows nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: Roll it back 1 version. Does it still persist? There are many other posts with this type of issue, sounds like a bug

Answer (score 0):

Users on the Opera Forums are experiencing the same problem. One of them [suggests](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1854654/inprovise-crash-when-i-open-the-settings/p1) that the issue may be related to a System Restore and/or the installation of a third-party software (SpyHunter, in their case).

Comment: Hm, I don't user SpyHunter, but I recently switched AntiVirus software.